# Can a non-throwing function pointer point to a throwing-function?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, noexcept

On C++ Primer on `noexcept` exception specification, it is said that a pointer to a function that may throw Implicitly (defined without exception specification e.g: `void(*p)();`) or explicitly (`void(*p)() noexcept(false);`) may point to any function even to a non-throwing function.

On the other hand a function pointer which may not throw (`noexcept` e.g `void(*p) noexcept;`) can only point to a function that won't throw.

I found that very logical because the first pointer it is OK to point to a non-throwing function from a throwing function pointer and the second too is so logical.

I've tried this to understand more:

```
void func1(){ // may throw
    std::cout << "func1()\n";
}

void func2() noexcept(false){ // may throw
    std::cout << "func2()\n";
}

void func3() noexcept(true){ // won't throw
    std::cout << "func3()\n";
}

void func4() noexcept{ // won't throw
    std::cout << "func4()\n";
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    void(*pFn1)();
    pFn1 = func1; // OK
    pFn1 = func2; // OK
    pFn1 = func3; // OK
    pFn1 = func4; // OK

    void(*pFn2)() noexcept(false);
    pFn2 = func1; // OK
    pFn2 = func2; // OK
    pFn2 = func3; // OK
    pFn2 = func4; // OK

    void(*pFn3)() noexcept(true);
    pFn3 = func1; // Error on C++ 17 and above. OK on C++11 and 14
    pFn3 = func2; // Error on C++ 17 and above. OK on C++11 and 14
    pFn3 = func3; // OK
    pFn3 = func4; // OK

    void(*pFn4)() noexcept(true);
    pFn4 = func1; // Error on C++ 17 and above. OK on C++11 and 14
    pFn4 = func2; // Error on C++ 17 and above. OK on C++11 and 14
    pFn4 = func3; // OK
    pFn4 = func4; // OK

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

- When I compile the program against `-std=c++17`, `-std=c++2a` it works as it should so I get the errors as I've written in the lines comments. But when I compile against `-std=c++11`, `-std=c++14` I get them all work and the compiler doesn't complain?!

Does this mean the standard has changed? Thank you!

Comment: It was probably unspecified in C++14 and below. Then somebody noticed the discrepancy, and they tightened up the requirements in C++17.

Comment: If you know what section of the standard your quote is coming from you can compare it against previous versions of the standard to see if it exists.

Comment: Looks like a GCC bug, [Clang and MSVC reject it](https://godbolt.org/z/P88s4n), and according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec#Explanation) it should be an error even before C++17.

Comment: This wordage (with a quick binary chop) seems to have been added in `2015-11-09` to [N4567](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4567.pdf) the previous version [n4527](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf) does not seem to have that wording. I found it in the section `[conv.fctptr]`

Comment: Looks like in C++14, the noexcept-ness was not part of the function type, so the declarations of `pFn1`, `pFn2`, `pFn3`, and `pFn4` are all equivalent except for the identifier. ([\[dcl.fct\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.fct), especially paragraphs 1-2 and the last normative sentence in 6)

Comment: @IlCapitano: I think you are correct because running the same program on Clang 7.0 with  `-std=c++11` it doesn't compile but on GCC it compiles so I think it is a bug in GCC. Please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's ill-formed in C++17 because the `noexcept` is part of the type system, and there is no conversion from a pointer to a potentially-throwing function to a pointer to a non-throwing function.

Before C++17 the relevant rule is [except.spec] p5:

> A similar restriction applies to assignment to and initialization of pointers to functions, pointers to member functions, and references to functions: the target entity shall allow at least the exceptions allowed by the source value in the assignment or initialization.

So although the `noexcept` isn't part of the type system, the OP's assignments are ill-formed.

G++ does not give an error for the example in p5:

```
class A { /* ... */ };
void (*pf1)(); // no exception specification
void (*pf2)() throw(A);

void f() {
  pf1 = pf2; // OK: pf1 is less restrictive
  pf2 = pf1; // error: pf2 is more restrictive
}
```

That should be ill-formed in C++98/11/14.

The equivalent with a noexcept-specifier would be:

```
class A { /* ... */ };
void (*pf1)(); // no exception specification
void (*pf2)() noexcept;

void f() {
  pf1 = pf2; // OK: pf1 is less restrictive
  pf2 = pf1; // error: pf2 is more restrictive
}
```

G++ doesn't reject this in 98/11/14, only C++17 and up.